# Get specific records of GridView based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get last tow values from the grid-view excluding the item with the zero price.

**Grid View Data**

```
ITEMCODE    ITEMNAME       PRICE
001         Ice Tea         5.0000
002         Super Delux     12.0000
003         Meditern Veg    0.0000
004         Super  L        0.0000
005         Super  L        33.0000
```

So desired output in this case is

```
Value1:005
Value2:002
```

**Code**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((row.Cells[2].Text != "0"))
        {
            count = (count + 1);
        }

    }

    Int32 Value1 = (count - 1);
    Int32 Value2 = (count - 2);
    lblValue1.Text = GridView1.Rows[Value1].Cells[0].Text;
    lblValue2.Text = GridView1.Rows[Value2].Cells[0].Text;
}
```

The code i have tired is not returning the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> CountRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
    for (int i = this.GridView1.Rows.Count-1; CountRows.Count < 2 || i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((double)this.GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != 0)
        {
            CountRows.Add(this.GridView1.Rows[i]);
        }

    }

    if(CountRows.Count >= 1)
    {
        lblValue1.Text = "Value1:" + CountRows[0].Cells[0].Text;
    }
    if(CountRows.Count == 2)
    {
        lblValue2.Text = "Value2:" + CountRows[1].Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

What I did was count from the end to the beginning using a regular for-loop, which stops when 2 rows are found or until the beginning is reached. Found rows are put in a list to hold them.

I used extra ifs at the end as not to get an index out of range exception when less than 2 rows are found (not in your example). Feel free to edit as you please.

Hope it helps!

Comment: hello thanks i have tried the code its working with my example but in another case i have tried the code its give this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: ITEMCODE    ITEMNAME       PRICE
001         Ice Tea         5.0000
002         Super Delux     0.0000
003         Meditern Veg    0.0000
004         Super  L        0.0000
005         Super  L        0.0000
006         Super  L        33.0000

Comment: I made a mistake in my for-line, I changed "i<0" to "i>=0". The loop must search until it reaches a negative value. It should work as expected now.